# Javascript to populate MVC dropdown

Tags: javascript, validation, razor, model-view-controller

I have a site that calculates prices dynamically based on the user selection from a drop down menu. At the minute, a user picks a category from the list and then this makes an AJAX call to a controller, which returns an amount of money and puts this into the 'total' field - this is readonly. 
So if I pick "male" it displays 20.00, "female" 15.00. 
I can open the Browser Developer tools and overwrite the amount with the statement: $("Amount").val("0.00").

This means people can adjust the amount owed from 20.00 to 0.00. I have added range validation to my model property of:
[Range(0.01, 999)]
but you could still adjust it.

Whats the best way of writing something like this to dynamically retrieve the total from an action but not allow it to be over-written?

Comment: If it's always read only then it doesn't need to be an input element, right?

Comment: I see where you are going...it will never be editable. Do you suggest another type?

I am currently using @Html.TextBoxFor() with a readonly html attribute

Comment: Yes, you want to be setting a private variable in your JS to hold that type of amount then. Look http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html for more info. Then, just use the innerHTML of a span element to show the pricing to the user. That way the user cannot modify it in the Web inspector.

Comment: If I change to a Span, I am still able to edit the value by doing:
document.getElementById('Fee').innerHTML = 0.00

Comment: That's correct. However, you should NOT be doing any calculations off of that. that is a display value only. You should be getting the price difference from a variable. Users can change DOM output all day long... but you should only be retrieving DOM values where their input matters. In this case, it sounds like you're worried that they can change the price. But really, they cannot. If you're getting this value from the DOM rather than a JS variable, then you should look at a better way to write this.